# Questions about the field of textual criticism without reference to a particular text

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I just asked this question:

[Textual criticism of the Hebrew bible and the rule of the ‘lectio difficilior'](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/18613/3555)

I imagine it should be on topic because I have a sense that local expertise is applicable. However, I’m not aware of a precedent, so I decided to look in the the help center:

---

***If your question is about...***

- interpretation of a specific Bible passage
- hermeneutical approaches
- translation of Biblical texts
- historical context (with regards to a particular text)
- source criticism

***... then this is the right place to ask.***

---

The topic of textual criticism was [addressed on meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/3555), and the conclusion was that it is on topic.* We have a tag [textual-criticism](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-criticism) which appears to be mostly appropriately applied. Among the questions I’ve looked through, though, all pertain to a specific passage. I think such questions were the focus of the prior meta question.

In the same way that exegesis and hermeneutical approaches are both on topic, I expect that applied textual criticism and the theory<sup>†</sup> of textual criticism are both on topic. Is this correct?

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> We probably should add a bullet to the above.</sup>


<sup><sup>†</sup> Can’t think of a better word, although this doesn’t seem to be especially theoretical. **Guidelines** for textual criticism?</sup>

Comment: "We probably should add a bullet to the above." - I don't think that would be a good idea, once you get beyone 4 or 5 bullets people stop reading any of them. That doesn't mean they shouldn't be changed to be clearer, but more bullets or longer text will actually make them less useful.

Comment: @Jack That makes sense. Maybe the fourth bullet could be expanded to say somethnig most people understand that includes both source and text criticism - "determining the original words of the Biblical text or the sources that influenced them" or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are on topic. We've [previously proposed changing our name to Biblical Studies](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/531/) or [Biblical Texts](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/164/423) (which avoids the association with bible studies) or another broader term implying the same concept (and even have [a roadmap for moving towards this](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/)) — personally I prefer 'Biblical Texts' but it doesn't have a lot of votes on that meta proposal — as a name change would better reflect our focus which includes a variety of sub-domains within the field of biblical studies.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know that we need any sort of name change, but adjusting that help center page to reflect the topicality of both levels of text criticism may be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think it's on topic, and everything like it.

> In the same way that exegesis and hermeneutical approaches are both on topic, I expect that applied textual criticism and the theory of textual criticism are both on topic. Is this correct?

Broadly we have on-topic questions about the text, and on-topic questions about questions about the text, so here on meta, we are really getting meta-meta when you ask a question like this, if you see what I mean.